# Tkinter align Grid place

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I create this little GUI with Tkinter. But I would like to have my button 'StartDate' and the button '...' and my Combobox aligned with my Entry object. I try to find a solution with pack(), but it's not good.

Do you have any idea?

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkcalendar import Calendar
    from tkinter.messagebox import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import *
    from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

    #------------------------------------ Configuration Tkinter ------------------------#
    #Conf General
    app = tk.Tk() 
    style = ttk.Style(app)
    style.theme_use('clam')
    app.geometry("320x260")
    app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
    app.attributes("-topmost", True)
    app.configure(background='#f4f4f4')
    #------------------------------------ Object Tkinter -------------------------------#
    #Code Alto
    selectalto = tk.Label(app,text = "Select Alto Code",bg='#f4f4f4')
    selectalto.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    selectalto_entry = Entry(app)
    selectalto_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    #Code PTF
    importCode = tk.Label(app,text = "Import Decalog Code",bg='#f4f4f4')
    importCode.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    browsebutton = tk.Button(app,text='...', bd = 0)
    browsebutton.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.N)
    #Date
    date_text = tk.Label(app,text = "Select Start Date",bg='#f4f4f4')
    date_text.grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    ttk.Button(app, text='Start Date').grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    #Views
    selectviews = tk.Label(app,text = "Select Views",bg='#f4f4f4')
    selectviews.grid(column=0, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    selectviews_entry = Entry(app, bd =1)
    selectviews_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    #Output
    selectouput = tk.Label(app,text = "Format Output",bg='#f4f4f4')
    selectouput.grid(column=0, row=4, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
    n = tk.StringVar() 
    selectouput_value = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable =n)
    selectouput_value.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="NW")
    selectouput_value['values'] = ['.csv', '.xlsx', '.txt', '.json']
    #BarProgress
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('clam')
    style.configure("blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar",foreground='#003c64', background='#003c64')
    my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(app,orient="horizontal",length=300,mode="determinate", style="blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
    my_progress.grid(columnspan = 2, row=6, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.N)
    my_progress['maximum'] = 100
    #Extraction
    ttk.Button(app, text='Extraction').grid(columnspan = 2, row=5, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.N)


    app.mainloop()
```

Tank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't line up because you have given them all different values of sticky, pad, and ipad. One way to be sure they all get the same value is to define it in a single dictionary and have them all use that dictionary, like this:

```
layout = dict(ipadx=5,pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
#Code Alto
selectalto = tk.Label(app,text = "Select Alto Code",bg='#f4f4f4')
selectalto.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
selectalto_entry = Entry(app)
selectalto_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, **layout)
#Code PTF
importCode = tk.Label(app,text = "Import Decalog Code",bg='#f4f4f4')
importCode.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
browsebutton = tk.Button(app,text='...', bd = 0)
browsebutton.grid(column=1, row=1, **layout)
# etc ..
```

Comment: It also helps if. you group all of your calls to `grid` together rather than scattering them throughout the code. That makes it much easier to visualize that the code is doing.

Comment: Hello Novel, it-s perfect ! Thank you for you help